# Renombrar nombre/mensaje de cualquier commit en un repositorio local sin modificar otros commits (2021)

Tags: git, vscode, terminal

Tengo una duda de como puedo hacer para cambiar el mensaje que tengo en un commit que no es necesariamente el ultimo, como puedo hacer para modificarlo con algún comando o de manera gráfica en una interfaz tipo visual studio code, ambas formas son útiles. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla es con un rebase interactivo. Digamos que la revision a la que le quieres modificar el comentario es la X:

```
git rebase -i X~ # atencion al rabo'e cochino, hay que ponerlo
# te va a salir una lista de revisiones, X deberia ser la primera
# cambias el pick por un reword o por una r
# guardas y sales del editor
# rebase se va a detener en esa revision y va a abrir un editor para que ajustes el comentario
# coloca lo que consideres adecuado
# guarda y sales
# el rebase termina de ejecutar y listo
```

Atencion: estas reescribiendo la historia. Esto se recomienda en ramas privadas o "feature branches", pero no en ramas **compartidas**.

Comment: la X seria el numero de commit?

Comment: el ID del commit.

Comment: Como guardo y salgo en vscode en el editor de commit que me aparecio

Comment: Depende del editor. Si es `vi` entonces hay que tipear: `[ESC]:wq[ENTER]`. Nano tiene un menu abajo que indica que hacer para guardar/salir. Si es otro editor, no tengo idea.

Comment: en visual studio code cuando pongo: git rebase -i IDNUMERO sin ~ me habre una ventana con todos los commit y su respectivo pick me di cuenta que no esta en la lista el primer commit y aparecen 6/7 commit que tengo lo que se me ocurrió fue agregarlo a la lista y poner el r pero en la interfaz me aparece el nombre pero no puedo editarlo desde la interfaz nose si es porque me falta teclear algun atajo y quizas nose guarde. casi casi lo estoy logrando algo debe de faltar

Comment: No, no esta bien porque git cuando vaya a hacer el rebase va a sacar justo la revision que quieres modificar y a partir de alli va a comenzar a operar (o sea, no la va a modificar). Creo que es bastante claro en la respuesta que se debe colocar `~`.

Comment: Tiene razón abrí otro commit y tampoco salio en la lista, agregue el carácter que faltaba y me arrojo esto: fatal: invalid upstream '548ac508~' no entiendo porque me sale ese mensaje o esta mal escrito

Comment: La revision `548ac508` es la primera de la rama? Si es asi, entonces lo que tienes que correr es `git rebase -i --root` (sin indicar la revision).

Comment: Ahora si me funciono, muchas gracias osea al final hay que escribir distinto solo para el primer commit, fue una edición exitosa se le agradece.

Comment: Es que si es la primera revision, es un "corner case"... al igual que si se trata de la ultima revision (en ese caso con un simple `git commit --amend` basta).

Comment: Tecnicamente hablando, en el rebase debes indicar la ultima revision que _no_ quieres tocar. Como la que quieres _tocar_ es la `548ac508`, entonces debes indicar `548ac508~`. El **rabo'e cochino** en git significa "el papá de". Y de esa forma se puede trabajar para todos los casos.... _excepto_ la primera revisión de una rama, que no tiene papá. En ese caso debes indicar `--root` para que git sepa que el rebase va incluyendo esa primera revisión (tomando **la nada** como el papá).

Comment: Lo máximo que bonito es el código cuando se encuentra una solución gracias stackoverflow  muchas gracias por la explicación dada. 

Answer (score 1):

Vas hasta nuestro repositorio que contiene el commit que quieres modificar.
Escribes
`git commit --amend` y pulsas Enter.

Se abre un editor de texto donde podrás modificar el mensaje del commit, y después deberemos guardar y cerrar.

Posteriormente  debes forzar un push para que sobreescriba el anterior commit, con el comando:

```
git push --force
```

Comment: Esto funciona si es el ultimo commit de una rama. Pero si no es el ultimo commit, hay que modificar mas revisiones. Lo mas sencillo en ese caso es con un `rebase -i`